# OfficeMenu not working with excel tables and pivot tables using office JS API

Tags: office-js, contextmenu, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I created an Excel add-in using Office JS API. This add-in **opens by selecting the Excel cell** and selecting the option from the **context menu by pressing right-click**.

For this behavior, I made changes in the manifest according below link to open an add-in from the context menu.
Link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/officemenu?view=excel-js-preview

The current behavior of add-in

[image]

But When I follow the **same steps with a table or pivot table my Excel add-in doesn't appear** on the context menu.

[image]

Please guide me on how to show the Excel add-in on context menu with table or there is any manifest changes required.

Comment: This might be a bug. I suggest that you create a bug issue on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose) repo. At least you can find out if this is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not all features of the Fluent UI are supported with Office web add-ins. You may consider creating a contextual tab for such scenarios, see [Create custom contextual tabs in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/contextual-tabs) for more information.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.